# MahApps Metro and DataGridExtensions

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mahapps.metro

In a project that I am starting I am using the 2 following libraries:

MahApps.Metro - http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/

DataGridExtensions - https://github.com/dotnet/DataGridExtensions

DatagridExtensions has some pretty nice datagrid filtering tools. The only problem is that using it removes the Metro style from the datagrid. Is there any way I can keep the Metro Styling on the datagrid and use the extensions.

The only .xaml file I could find in the DataGridExtensions library was the generic.xaml file. I modified this to include BasedOn in any styles in there, as this has worked in the past:

e.g.

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}>
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting a default header style solved the problem for me:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridColumnHeader}" />
```

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: @NahumLitvin well, adding the style in the answer to `App.xaml` solved the issue for me, it restored the `DataGrid` style for filtered columns. Not much more to say at this point, I didn't really dig further.